# GetLocaleFormatSettings for LOCALE_INVARIANT returns the users settings under Windows XP German

Tags: delphi, localization, delphi-2010

All numbers that I write to files for exchange purpose use the following code:

```
GetLocaleFormatSettings(LOCALE_INVARIANT, fsInvariant);
FloatToStrF(Value, fsInvariant);
```

When I read in the number I use this

```
GetLocaleFormatSettings(LOCALE_INVARIANT, fsInvariant);
if TryStrToFloat(value, floatval, fsInvariant) then
  result := floatVal
```

That works under Windows 7, incl. the German version, but fails in the German version of Windows XP.

The problem seems to be in the GetLocaleFormatSettings procedure since it gives me the same values under for LOCALE_INVARIANT and LOCALE_DEFAULT_USER.

Here some code that shows the my issue:

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Grids, ValEdit;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    VLEditor: TValueListEditor;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  fsInvariant : TFormatSettings;
  fsLocaleUser : TFormatSettings;
begin
  GetLocaleFormatSettings(LOCALE_INVARIANT, fsInvariant);
  VLEditor.InsertRow('Invariant Decimal Seperator', fsInvariant.DecimalSeparator, true);
  VLEditor.InsertRow('Invariant Thousand Seperator', fsInvariant.ThousandSeparator , true);
  VLEditor.InsertRow('Invariant List Seperator', fsInvariant.ListSeparator , true);

  GetLocaleFormatSettings(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, fsLocaleUser);
  VLEditor.InsertRow('Locale Decimal Seperator', fsLocaleUser.DecimalSeparator, true);
  VLEditor.InsertRow('Locale Thousand Seperator', fsLocaleUser.ThousandSeparator, true);
  VLEditor.InsertRow('Locale List Seperator', fsLocaleUser.ListSeparator, true);
end;

end.
```

When I run the exe in Windows XP Pro - SP3 - GERMAN, it displays the same characters for  the same separators. In the German Windows 7, it shows up as expected.

What am I missing here? How come it gives different output?

Thanks,
Thomas

**Update:** 
`GetLocaleFormatSettings` checks first if the LCID is valid by using the kernel32 function `IsValidLCID(LCID, LCID_INSTALLED)`. The issue is with the use of `LCID_INSTALLED` rather than `LCID_SUPPORTED`. The `LOCALE_INVARIANT` is supported, but not installed on Windows XP systems. Therefore the `GetLocaleFormatSettings` routine reverts always to the users LCID.

What is the best way of fixing it? Write my own GetLocaleFormatSettings routine? Change the code in Delphi's SysUtils.pas file?

Comment: If you do not call `GetLocaleFormatSettings()` often, it makes sense to write your own for isolated usages. If you use it often, it makes sense to patch and recompile `SysUtils` instead. BTW, the `LCID_INSTALLED` issue still exists in XE3, so I would suggest reporting it as a bug to QC.

Comment: I decided to create a global variable for the invariant settings, that I fill manually. The settings should never change anyway. I left the `SysUtils` code untouched, just to avoid having unintended side effects when changing `LCID_INSTALLED` to `LCID_SUPPORTED`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Earlier versions of Delphi did have problems initializing `TFormatSettings` correctly.  For instance, D2010 does have an intialization bug regarding the `ShortMonthNames`, `LongMonthNames`, `ShortDayNames`, and `LongDayNames` arrays when the specified LCID is not installed (but that does not affect your example).  There have been formatting-related bug fixes in newer releases.

In some cases, calling `SetThreadLocale()` and `GetFormatSettings()` in a unit's `initialization` section helps address formatting issues.

FYI, `GetLocaleFormatSettings()` is now deprecated in recent releases, in favor of a new `TFormatSettings.Create()` method:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  fsInvariant : TFormatSettings;
  fsLocaleUser : TFormatSettings;
begin
  fsInvariant := TFormatSettings.Create(LOCALE_INVARIANT);
  ...
  fsLocaleUser := TFormatSettings.Create(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Unfortunately in Delphi 2010 the `TFormatSettings.Create()` method is not available. I will try to get something working `SetThreaddLocale()`.

Comment: `TFormatSettings.Create()` was added in XE.